# Flex Box out of borders?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I have been trying to make a flex box in CSS like the image below[image]

but I have a problem that's look like this image [image]

it seems like the div number 3 push every thing down here is the code

```
#flexcontainer
{
width: 500px;
height: 210px;
border: 3px solid black;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 5px;

}

.flexitem
{
background: yellow;
width : 150px;
text-align: center;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
margin: 2px;
}

.two
{
width : 200px;
}
.three
{
width : 120px;
height: 100%;
}
```

I also tried to use align-self property and set it to stretch to .three but also it doesn't work. Here is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            Project Name
        </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div id="flexcontainer">
    <div class="flexitem one">1</div> 
    <div class="flexitem two">2</div> 
    <div class="flexitem three">3</div> 
    <div class="flexitem four">4</div> 
    <div class="flexitem four">5</div> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can wrap flex *columns* and then reorder the children:

```css
#flexcontainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 210px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.flexitem {
  background: yellow;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.two {
  width: 200px;
  order: 3;
}

.three {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  order: 5;
}

.five { order: 4; }
```

```html
<div id="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexitem one">1</div>
  <div class="flexitem two">2</div>
  <div class="flexitem three">3</div>
  <div class="flexitem four">4</div>
  <div class="flexitem five">5</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/12xkrtp4/